# Draw a painting or paint a drawing?

Tags: synonyms, descriptive-grammar

'Paint a painting' or 'draw a drawing' sounds repetitive but 'paint a drawing' or 'draw a painting' sounds kinda weird, you don't actually use paint to draw, right?

And if I'm applying paint over existing pencil drawing that IMO should be called 'coloring a drawing'.

So how do I correctly name this? 'Draw/paint a picture' maybe?

Comment: Are you looking for a word to describe the action or the end result?

Comment: @KillingTime I thought the result would be 'a painting' or 'a drawing' i.e. noun. So i'm looking for words to describe the process

Comment: You could use 'make' or 'create'.

Comment: Applying paint over pencil can just be part of the painting process, some artists start a piece with a pencil outline. I wouldn't call that "colouring".

Comment: @Weather Vane 'Execute a painting' rarely sounds fitting, but you shoulkd see my early efforts.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth well I *hung* my last painting after I had *framed* it.

Comment: Is it still life?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I shall ask the Constable.

Answer (score 2):

A thing that is painted is a painting. A thing that is drawn is a drawing. Drawing is different from painting. That's why it "sounds kinda weird" - drawing a painting or painting a drawing is wrong.

It's also true that "draw a drawing" or "paint a painting" is repetitive. You can get round it be saying "draw/paint a picture" or "make a drawing/painting".

Comment: Further to this (but not worth a separate answer), there are lots of ways to avoid repetitive phrasing: This morning I did a painting. This afternoon I'm working on a drawing. Mary painted a landscape. Dave drew a portrait. Wendy creates wonderful watercolours.

Answer (score 1):

> And if I'm applying paint over existing pencil drawing that IMO should be called 'coloring a drawing'.
>
> So how do I correctly name this?

You would call this **overpainting** or **painting over** the drawing; [Merriam-Webster indicates](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overpaint) that the two are synonymous.